# Why is this div not centering properly?

Tags: html, css, layout, tumblr

Starting my first Tumblr layout.
For some reason, the columns are all a little to the left, and not centered within #content.

Not sure what I am doing wrong... any help would be very much appreciated.

Also... if anyone viewing this has any advice or sees a better way of doing these columns, I would love to hear it.

Thanks
Sam

Code:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<style>
body {
    text-align: center;
}
#wrap {
    height: auto px;
    width: 920px;
    margin: 15px auto;
    border: 1px black solid;
}
#header {
    margin: 10px;
}
#content {
}
#column1 {
}
#column2 {
}
#column3 {
}
#footer {
}
.title {
    font-size:25px;
}
.subtitle {
    font-size:16px;
}
.column {
    width: 300px;
    float: left;

}
</style>
<title>{title}</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrap">
<div id="header">
<div class="title">
{title}</div>
<div class="subtitle">
{description}</div>
</div>
<div id="content">
<div id="column1" class="column">
column1
</div>
<div id="column2" class="column">
column2
</div>
<div id="column3" class="column">
column3
</div>
</div>
<div id="footer" class="subtittle">
copyright {copyrightYears} {title}
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your container is more than 900px (300px x 3) wide.

Set column width to 33.3% (near enough 1/3 of the container width).

```
.column {
    width:33.3%;
    float: left;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CZ9Lw/